# Custom point markers in Matlab Mapping Toolbox?

Tags: matlab, matlab-mapping-toolbox

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to create custom point markers (from some image files) in Matlab with Mapping Toolbox.

So far, I haven't found anything about this in their documentation. Online searches only yielded:

> No. The marker shapes are hard-coded and you cannot add new ones. If you want a custom 
>   marker, then at each point you want the marker, you will have to use line() or 
>   equivalent to draw the marker or image() or equivalent to draw in an image.

(Source: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.matlab/browse_thread/thread/4fe4e31f191f7080)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation there is this [page](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/map/ref/wmmarker.html) it can interesting you with this paragraph:

**You can draw Marker Using Custom Icon and Description Data:**

Define location.

```
lat =  42.299827;
lon = -71.350273;
```

Specify text in description balloon and name.

```
description = sprintf('%s<br>%s</br><br>%s</br>',...
                      '3 Apple Hill Drive', 'Natick, MA. 01760', ...
                      'http://www.mathworks.com');
 name = 'The MathWorks, Inc.';
```

Specify custom icon.

```
iconDir = fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','matlab','icons');
iconFilename = fullfile(iconDir, 'matlabicon.gif');
```

Draw marker on web map, specifying Description, FeatureName, Icon, and OverlayName. wmmarker creates the web map. In the illustration, note the custom icon and the HTML formatting in the description.

```
wmmarker(lat, lon, 'Description', description, ...
                   'FeatureName', name,... 
                   'Icon', iconFilename,... 
                   'OverlayName', name);
```